# What does "notwithstanding" mean in the Supremacy Clause of the U.S. Constitution?

Tags: word-usage

> This Constitution, and the Laws of the United States which shall be made in Pursuance thereof; and all Treaties made, or which shall be made, under the Authority of the United States, shall be the supreme Law of the Land; and the Judges in every State shall be bound thereby, any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary **notwithstanding**.

According to Dictionary.com, notwithstanding means "nevertheless,yet,anyway", but it does not make sense here to me. Is it some kind of legal use here?

Comment: The sentence means roughly this: "The state judges in every individual state of the United States are obligated to uphold the provisions of all national laws of the United States made under the authority of the U.S. Constitution, regardless of whether contrary or conflicting provisions exist in the constitution or laws of their particular state."

Comment: 'Notwithstanding' is a postposition here: 'any apparently or actually conflicting ruling by any other jurisdiction notwithstanding' = [determiner +] NP + postposition. It means  'notwithstanding any apparently or actually conflicting ruling by any other jurisdiction' where the word is used as the preposition, and again means, as Sven says, 'regardless of' (though 'regardless of' can't be placed after the NP). Postpositions as a class are rare in English. 'Ago' is a commonly used member of the class.

Comment: the Judges in every State shall be bound thereby, *despite* any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary.

Answer (score 4):

There's a flaw in how you are understanding dictionary glosses of a word, when you assume those glosses can simply be plugged into any sentence in exactly the same location as the word they gloss. Dictionaries gloss a word's meaning, not its syntactic role.

Consider something Mom is saying to Junior:

> You're going to eat all your vegetables, anything your father may have said to the contrary notwithstanding.

The word "notwithstanding" might be glossed as "despite" but you couldn't simply plop the word **despite** down into the sentence in the same place as the word whose *meaning* it glosses:

> You're going to eat all your vegetables, anything your father may have said to the contrary **despite**. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

You would have to reorder:

> You're going to eat all your vegetables, **despite** anything your father may have said to the contrary.

The practical meaning is the same but the syntactic role differs.

Answer (score 0):

> This Constitution, and the Laws of the United States […] shall be the supreme Law of the Land; and the Judges in every State shall be bound thereby, any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary notwithstanding.

This should be understood in the light of The Constitution and federal law being the final word on any constitutional or legal subject.

> The preemption doctrine originates from the supremacy clause of Article 6 of the U.S. Constitution. This doctrine states that any federal law, even if it is only a regulation from a federal agency, supersedes any conflicting state law, even if that law is part of the state's constitution. See https://smallbusiness.chron.com/state-labor-laws-supercede-federal-labor-laws-56969.html

Thus if the Constitution or federal law says you must eat cabbage once a day, but Arkansas State law or constitution says cabbage is illegal, then the Arkansas law is invalid.

Thus

This Constitution, and Federal Law […] shall be the supreme Law of the Land; and the Judges in every State shall be bound thereby, **even if there is a local, state, or city law that claims to be superior to, or dismiss, or be contrary to the Constitution, and the Laws of the United States.**

Comment: This is essentially correct, but the bolded part adds several components that are not in the actual text. One may say that these additional components are obviously **implied** by the text, but in saying this one would be engaged in legal interpretation. As has already been pointed out in the comments, what confused the OP in that sentence is that the word *notwithstanding* appears after the phrase 'any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary'; that confusion can be easily dispelled by just replacing it with *despite* positioned **before** the phrase.

Answer (score -4):

The Supremacy Clause is the most difficult to understand clause for a non-lawyer to understand. As a non-lawyer, I must submit an answer with the same opinion flaw: "any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary notwithstanding" means "any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary [is null and void]." I submit this means no contradiction to Article IV, Section 4 can be added to our Constitution, or to any law. For example, an Amendment or law stating: "The First Amendment is hereby repealed" would be null and void.

Comment: No, what it says is that the Federal Constitution overrules the State Constitutions, not that it overrules itself. We have repealed Constitutional Amendments before (the 21st Amendment repealed the 18th), and a Constitutional Amendment could repeal the First or Second Amendment (a law couldn't).

Comment: *despite* any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State. His smile notwithstanding, I found his temper to be a problem=despite his smile. Does one really need to be a lawyer? It only goes back to the comma, meaning-wise.